# How to invoke J2ee application's method from GWT application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, smartgwt

I have two apps deployed in the server, one is a GWT app and other is a normal j2ee app. Now in one particular scenario, on submission in the GWT app i need to call one business method from the j2ee app along with some parameters. How can this be achieved? Another point, need to show the response in the j2ee app itself and not in the GWT app.

Comment: By "ivoking from GWT" You mean from GWT client side or server side? Server side is just a regular Servlet base app, so You can use any way You want to call other service (JNDI or something else). If You want to call J2EE app directly from GWT client side, You can try to use RequestBuilder 
http://www.g-widgets.com/2016/09/09/gwt-http-requests-alternatives/

Comment: If you already have a GWT app, then it should be already communicated with the server side. You should use the same communication strategy! Or, are you learning and creating a new app and asking for advice?